# In rails, what is the recommended way to sanitize user input for order inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, sql-injection, sanitization

I understand the hashing and parameterization methods for the where methods, but i'm running into problem trying to run input into order().

Specifically, I am trying to order the results by the closest match to the input using `.order(["levenshtein(lower(name), ?)",[@form.name.downcase]])`.  Because this include a method with arguments used as raw sql, I get the following warning.

```
Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): 
"levenshtein(lower(name), ?)". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.1. 
This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. 
Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().
```

To try to work around this, I tried to implement [sanitize_sql_for_order](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_order) and changed my order to `.order(MyClass.sanitize_sql_for_order(["levenshtein(lower(name), ?)",[@form.name.downcase]]))`. It appears to be escaping properly `ORDER BY levenshtein(lower(name), 'test ''2')` but I keep getting the same warning as above.

I know that I can wrap my raw sql in `Arel.sql()` but even that [calls out specifically that it should not be used with user input](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Arel.html).  Note that the sanitize_sql_for_order method is calling Arel.sql within its processing.

What is the rails recommended way of using user input for an order statement, so it properly escapes it to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: How're you implementing the `Arel.sql(...)` part?

Comment: @SebastianPalma .order(MyClass.sanitize_sql_for_order([Arel.sql("levenshtein(lower(name), ?)"),[@form.name.downcase]])) which does remove the warning, but since the arel documentation says it is only for known safe sql, I'm not thinking this is the best way.

Comment: Try removing the `MyClass.sanitize_sql_for_order(...)`, leaving only Arel.sql inside `order`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks for your response.  It does make the warning go away by wrapping it in Arel.sql(). But is this this the "right" way to sanitize user provided input, or untrusted data when including it for results ordering?

Comment: As far as I know, this is "enough". You can check [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32995) never-ending Github issue.